# Trashing Market Square and another card at the same time

Tags: dominion, dominion-dark-ages

I use a card that allows me to trash 2 cards from my hand (like Chapel).  I trash Market Square and another card.  Are the cards trashed simultaneously or sequentially?  Does either possibility allow me to use Market Square's effect?  If so, where does the Market Square end up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cards are trashed at the same time, so if you are trashing Market Square, you would not be allowed to discard Market Square for its effect also.

> You choose all the cards you want to trash, and then trash them at the same time; you don't trash them one-by-one. This matters for interactions with Dark Ages cards with on-trash abilities.

[Dominion Strategy Wiki](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Chapel)

Also, from the Dark Ages rulebook:

> When two or more cards are trashed at the same time, as with Count, first trash them all, then pick an order to resolve things that happen due to trashing them.

Comment: While I'm not disputing this ruling, it does seem to go against how Alchemist is handled: you can discard your played cards in the cleanup step in whatever order you choose, allowing you to get your Alchemist back before discarding your potion.  Is trashing the only game action where multiple instances happen simultaneously?  How does that work?

Comment: The rules in Alchemy specifically state that when discarding cards from play, cards can be cleaned up in any order. With actions such as Cellar and Warehouse, which have you discard multiple cards, cards are discarded at the same time (though of course they need to end up in some order in the discard pile. But your opponent's don't get to see every card you discarded, only the one that ends up on top).

Comment: @codebreaker To add to what Gendolkari said, the rules in Dark Ages specifically state "When two or more cards are trashed at the same time, as with Count, first trash them all, then pick an order to resolve things that happen due to trashing them."  However, Market Square has to be in your hand to be used as a Reaction, but your Chapel already put it in the trash.  Besides which, even if you could do them one by one, by discarding Market Square, it's no longer in your hand to trash.

Comment: @Powerlord, thanks for that; I edited it into the response.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that about the cleanup step working like that.  Just out of curiosity, when you gain multiple cards (like from Develop, Thief, and Beggar, for example), does that happen all at once?  Or does the simultaneous thing only apply to discarding/ trashing?

If you had Watchtower out and the gains happened simultaneously, wouldn't that cause Watchtower to lose track of all but one of them?

Comment: I believe Donald X. clarified at one point that gains have to happen one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You can't gain a gold by trashing Market Square, only by discarding it.  Once you've trashed it you can't then discard it.  Consequently you can't gain a gold by using Chapel to trash it and another card.

The only way I can see to trash the Market Square **and** use its ability is by discarding it, reshuffling, picking it up again and then trashing it.  This could be done using the Doctor with a bit of luck (or a very small deck):

- Play a Gold and a Silver
- Buy a Doctor for 5 (overpaying by 2)
- Pick up the only card in your deck and trash it (Doctor overpay ability 1)
- Discard Market Square from your hand and gain a Gold
- Shuffle your discard pile and place as a new deck
- Draw the top card (which turns out to be the same Market Square) and trash it (Doctor overpay ability 2)